# Youtube player api + phonegap doesn't work

Tags: android, ios, cordova, youtube

We are trying to use the YouTube API V3 in our Phonegap (2.9.2) application. A video is supposed to be displayed with the following code:

> ```
>   <video class="col-xs-12" id="ytplayer" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ek3ZZn3KwzA"></video>
> ```

```
        // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api?enablejsapi=1&version=3";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {

        player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
            events: {

            }
        });
    }
```

We can only see a grey rectangle with a play button in it, on both Android (4.2) and iOS (7) devices.

What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
<div id="player"> </div> 

var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {

      videoId: 'P2jViqMnnK4',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
         'onError': onError,

      },
      playerVars: {

                'controls': 0,
                'showinfo': 0,
                'iv_load_policy': 3,
            },
    });
}
```